# How to customize list/menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Well. i am hoping to find a solution to customize List/Menu with CSS which is also cross browser compatible.

Comment: Well. I have found a solution with javascript at this link:
[link](http://gerrendesign.com/weblog/2009/06/how_to_make_custom_select_boxe.php)
but i was wondering if i could do it with CSS:

Comment: "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas!"

Answer (score 0):

Neat CSS menu creator: http://www.cssmenumaker.com/, or you could always google 'CSS Menu'

Answer (score 0):

The markup might go something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

If horizontal menu is needed, you have to float `<li>s` by giving them fixed width.

```
li { 
width: 100px; /*Fixed width is important to float, because li is a block level element*/
float: left;
}
```

If vertical menu is needed, just give a width to `<ul>` according to your layout

adding `display:block;` to the `<a>` will greatly improve the usablity of menus, since it makes the whole `<li>`s clickable links